# Database triggers that are being used to log history seem to be causing deadlock exceptions?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am getting Dead Lock exceptions in my C# code when I call my stored procedure to update/insert into my `Configuration` table.

The `SP_Update_Configuration` stored procedure will either insert a new record or update an existing record.

The Triggers are setup to keep a history of previous records in a history table. If the `Configuration` table has an update or an insert, then it should add that record to the `Configuration_History` table.

I believe the triggers are causing the deadlock? I did not have any problems previous to adding triggers.... Any Ideas?

I am using SQL Server 2012 Express.

Here is an example of my SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Update_Configuration
( 
--Input variables
) 
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @RetCode INT
DECLARE @RowCnt INT
    --Standard Update Logic
SELECT @RowCnt = @@ROWCOUNT

IF @@ERROR <> 0
   BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRAN
    SET @RetCode = 5
    RETURN @RetCode
   END

IF @RowCnt = 0
    BEGIN
        --Standard Insert Logic
    END

IF @@ERROR <> 0
   BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRAN
    SET @RetCode = 5
    RETURN @RetCode
   END

COMMIT TRANSACTION
GO

create trigger dbo.Configuration_Log_Insert 
on dbo.Configuration
  for insert
as
  set nocount on
  insert into Configuration_History
    select *
      from Configuration
go

exec sp_settriggerorder @triggername = 'Configuration_Log_Insert', @order = 'last', @stmttype = 'insert'  

create trigger dbo.Configuration_Log_Update 
on dbo.Configuration
  for update
as
  set nocount on
  insert into Configuration_History
    select *
      from Configuration
go

exec sp_settriggerorder @triggername = 'Configuration_Log_Update', @order = 'last', @stmttype = 'update'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT @RowCnt = @@ROWCOUNT

IF @@ERROR <> 0
```

here you have trouble, because `@@ERROR` is error code of

```
SELECT @RowCnt = @@ROWCOUNT
```

You can do this as:

```
SELECT @RowCnt = @@ROWCOUNT, @error = @@ERROR

IF @error <> 0
```

In triggers you have

```
  insert into Configuration_History
    select *
      from Configuration
```

but is must be

```
  insert into Configuration_History
    select *
      from inserted
```

Comment: I will make these changes and test if I still receive the deadlock exception. I did not know about the @@Error issues, I have been using these stored procedures and they are updating/inserting properly. I am not sure if it is actually an issue.

Comment: Thanks, this appears to have remedied the exceptions. I will test more thoroughly before I close the question. Cheers!